# Maven doesn't upload maven-metadata.xml with mvn-golang-wrapper plugin

Tags: maven, go, maven-metadata

I use [mvn-golang-wrapper](https://github.com/raydac/mvn-golang) plugin to build binary for Go project, and *maven-assembly-plugin* to pack that binary and some related files to a *.tar.gz* artifact. To make *mvn-golang-wrapper* work, I specify `<packaging>mvn-golang</packaging>` in my *pom.xml*.

The issue is that with `<packaging>mvn-golang</packaging>`, when Maven uploads the *.tar.gz* to the artifactory, it doesn't create nor update *maven-metadata.xml* there. If I remove the `<packaging>` tag, *maven-metadata.xml* gets created, but, of course, Go binary doesn't get built.

Just in case, Maven is being run on TeamCity CI.

Comment: What version of Maven is this? Do you have a sample `pom.xml` and very basic app that you could show this with?

Comment: since 2.1.8 version there was improved compatibility with standard install and deploy goals